# Deciding which Amazon AWS back-end schema/setup for iOS app

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've decided I'm going to use all Amazon AWS services for an app I'm building, but am not quite sure what would be the best/fastest setup for my needs.

My plan is to use S3 as the storage for user's content (photos). CloudFront will deliver the user's content stored in S3.

Now, for the database part, it doesn't need to be complicated; the database will only have things like: friends associated with each user, blocked users, denied friend requests, unique identifier for each thing posted/shared, username/email, and a password. The user's shared text string could be stored in the database, and the associated photo would need a key to the S3 location.

Can anyone recommend a good AWS solution/product to integrate all the above. It needs to be extremely fast and scalable automatically with little to no interaction to scale it. Also, cost isn't a big issue. Is EC2 even needed? It may seem that this will come down to either RDS or DynamoDB perhaps? Sorry for the nested questions in advance.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: It may be worth looking into [Parse](https://parse.com/) which will help you create a backend for your mobile app very easily without having to worry about deploying servers and scaling.

Comment: Looked into Parse, and don't want to go with them as they're owned by FB now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are experienced with MySQL that I believe you should throw an RDS for start. The instances today can be pretty big and you can benefit from memcache inside the server + other stuff.. I seriously doubt it won't hold and when it doesn't, you might have a big-enough app to consider solutions not "hosted" by AWS.

In my mind DynamoDB is harder to prototype since you need to declare your indexes when you create the table.

EC2 needed? do you mean you are considering a backend-less solution? I don't really understand why you'd want to go that road.. It is best to separate backend from client for modularity.

You can hide EC2 by using beanstalk/opsworks or even deploy to Heroku.

Comment: I don't need to use EC2 for RDS, correct? Since RDS scales fine without EC2? Thanks again sir.

Comment: You can think of RDS as a "hosted-ec2". It is in fact an EC2 running a database server, but AWS takes care of minor updates, backups, etc. So no, you don't need it for RDS, but you will probably need some server to interact with the database